# How to use prototyping boards

Tags: pcb, prototyping

I am new to Electrical Engineering, in fact I'm more of a hardware hacker. But I am wondering how to prototype circuit boards, on something like this:

[image: prototype board photo from Ebay]

<sub>[Photo cropped from this Ebay auction link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Universal-Double-Side-Board-PCB-1-27mm-1-6mm-2-54mm-DIY-Prototype-Paper-PCB/121413587634)</sub>

I don't know how to use one. So I would appreciate some resources.

Comment: Well, err. Maybe you'd want to start with some basic electronics DIY kits to learn how to solder together stuff before you head out and buy solder/prototyping boards.

Comment: Please search google before posting: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+proto+boards&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: This seems like the answers will be high-tech versions of *"100 uses for a dead cat"*.

Comment: I would suggest to start prototyping without a board. The need for it will come naturally, and you will be able to answer the question yourself.

Comment: Thank you for all of you're help. I just needed my mine to click from a PCB to something where I have to set jumper wires where there would be carbon, or etch traces.

Comment: Sometimes a question is just misunderstood. He meant, how do you connect the dots? You can use clippings from component leads, or wires from TP cable  (Computer Network)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use through-hole components to put the leads through the holes in your proto-board then you will need to solder them to the pins and each pin to other pins to make your desired connections.

A quick google search for 'how to solder proto board' or similar will give you some guidance. For example: http://www.instructables.com/id/Led-Cube-8x8x8/step32/Build-the-controller-protoboard-soldering-advice/

If you've never used a soldering iron before go ahead and look up guides for using one of those as well. Good luck!

Comment: I have a soldering Iron that I am good at, from previous hardware hacking knowledge. But now I am trying my hand at electrical engineering.I found something called a perfboard, which I think is what you are talking about. I have orderd 10 of these and 1 breadboard starter kit with lots of PCB parts e.g. Capacitor Resistor transistor

Comment: However follow up question, I haven't gotten my hands on any jumpers yet, they come in a couple of days. But can you solder jumper wires. I believe they're male to male

Comment: You can solder jumper wires probably but that isn't their intended purpose - they are useful for fast prototyping on breadboards. I would recommend buying some spools of insulated wire and wire strippers to make your own custom length wires for soldering to your perfboard. Solid core wire would be good for this and much cheaper than using your (more expensive) jumper wires for a permanent connection.

Comment: Thank you very much you've been very helpful, one last question. What guage?

Comment: As long as it fits in the holes and is rated for the current through it, whatever works (probably 22 to 30 AWG just guessing)